# Regex Exceptions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to come up with a java regex that will match numbers with 2 too 3 decimals and not match any decimal number more than 3.

this is my regex

```
[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}
```

It matches `41.51778000` and `18.740`

but I only want it to match numbers that have exactly 3 decimal places and not numbers with more than three

Answer (score 1):

You must use word boundary on either side to stop unexpected matches:

```
\b[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2,3}\b
```

In Java it would be:

```
\\b\\d{2}\\.\\d{2,3}\\b
```

Comment: Or maybe start and end anchors!

Comment: Yes right but since I haven't see full input from OP I thought safer to use `\b`

Comment: Do boundaries work in java pattern class? It seems like some regex does not work in java.

Comment: @Joseph: Of course word boundary will work in Java's `Pattern` class

Comment: Is the a certain reason you have to use the \\ in java?

Comment: Yes because one \ is needed by `String` and other is needed by RegEx engine

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the regex to match the end and start as well.

```
^[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `Matcher#matches` or `String.matches` instead of, say, `Matcher#find` to match the whole `String`.

Otherwise, you can prepend `^` and append `$` to your pattern, to delimit start and end of input.

Finally, you can surround your pattern with something like `\\D`, or `\\b` or `\\w` to respectively match non-digits, word boundaries or whitespace around it, if you need to invoke `find` on an input containing more than 1 instance of the pattern.